# How to declare custom function into Repository on Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, doctrine

I'm trying do a pagination into my symfony project with this tutorial: [pagination symfony2](http://www.6ma.fr/tuto/une+pagination+performante+avec+symfony-777)

But when I need to add a custom function into my classRepository for example to count all rows in a table, I get the error: "Undefined method 'getList'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!"

The function to get a list of all rows I can do:

```
public function findAllUsers()
{

    return $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')
        ->findAll();
}
```

But the new function I can't add...

How can I add functions into classRepository?

Thanks!

Comment: http://masnun.com/2012/11/12/symfony2-doctrine-custom-entity-repositories.html

Comment: It is because you don't have your custom repository properly mapped to the entity.  Search a bit.  At last count there were 749 stackoverflow questions for the exact same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to add the annotation of the repository class name at the beginning of Users Entity class.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UsersRepository")
 */
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes